# Insert selection mariadb query

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I am trying to insert into table A where one of it's value need to be selected from table B. I used the below query.

```
INSERT INTO `TableA` (`TableACol1`,`TableACol2`) VALUES ( 4, SELECT `TableBcol1` FROM `TableB` WHERE FirstName="shasha" )
```

I don't know what's going wrong with this but facing this error.

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax

Answer (score 2):

Insert the `"4"` inside the `select`

```
INSERT INTO `TableA` (`TableACol1`,`TableACol2`)
SELECT 4, `TableBcol1` FROM `TableB` WHERE FirstName="shasha"
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html

Comment: Thanks @Roy  . This one worked I just missed bunch of parenthesis. INSERT INTO `TableA` (`TableACol1`,`TableACol2`) VALUES ( 4, (SELECT `TableBcol1` FROM `TableB` WHERE FirstName="shasha" ))

Comment: Your link helped me Thanks @Roy

Comment: @shasha Nice, good coding!